# Jquery selectMenu creates line break (can't get it to display inline)

Tags: jquery, html, select-menu

I have a few select elements:

```
<div id="divReports">
<select id="ddlReportTypes" style="width:200px;"></select>
<select id="ddlReportFarms" style="width:200px;"></select> 
<select id="ddlReportClusters" style="width:200px;"></select>
</div>
```

they display themselves just fine, in the same line

when I turn them into selectMenus like this:

```
$("#divReports select").selectmenu({
style: 'dropdown',
transferClasses: true
});
```

they refuse to be inline , and each one occupies a whole line
this is the html as seen on firebug:

```
<select id="ddlReportTypes" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
<a id="ddlReportTypes-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default      ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-corner-all" aria-owns="ddlReportTypes-menu" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" style="width: 200px;">
<span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Traffic variance report </span>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</a>

<select id="ddlReportFarms" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
<a id="ddlReportFarms-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" aria-owns="ddlReportFarms-menu" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" style="width: 200px; display: block;">

<select id="ddlReportClusters" style="width: 200px; display: none;">
<a id="ddlReportClusters-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" aria-owns="ddlReportClusters-menu" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" role="button" style="width: 200px; display: block;">
```

I've tried style="display:inline", doesn't work..
I've made the  tag display:inline, but that only made it worse..

any ideas anyone?
10x

Comment: you miss quote `"` in your 2nd and 3rd `select` element `style` property, correct them and recheck

Comment: thanks thecodeparadox, but it's a copy-paste error when I pasted here. my original code is fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check that and it looks like jQuery UI added "display: block" to newly created elements:

```
.ui-selectmenu {
    display: block;
}
```

Solution would be to overwrite it, but display: inline, won't help, we need something like, inline-block, ideally cross browser:

```
.ui-selectmenu {
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline; /* To make IE7 happy */ 
} ​​​​​​​
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/demee/YJVhG/2/